# Python/PySpark parallel processing example

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having trouble understanding how to utilize the power of parallel processing in my python script.

I have a billion row database of food items, e.g:

```
date,item,category,number_sold
2017-01-01,bagel,bread,10
2017-03-03,skittles,candy,5
```

There are 100 categories. (bread, candy, etc.) my script:

```
1. Iterates list of 100 categories
2. Filter pyspark dataframe for the subset (e.g. category == 'bread')
3. Run aggregate calculations on subset
4. Generate 1 row of stats and appends to summary file
```

What do I need to add into the iterative loop to trigger multi-processing? Does pyspark do this automatically? When I ran this only using Pandas, the script was held up (not doing anything) while waiting to query each category subset. Ideally, the process should filter the dataframe for one category and run calculations for another category at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First short list items (step 2) and process them in separate threads. Implementation of multithreading is very easy in python. Write each report in a separate file and finally marge all the files and make the final report.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit further? the script would need to first map the data relevant to each of the 100 categories? 
Then let the calculations occur?

Comment: Do you need a shorted output? If so you have to follow step 2 first. Else split the file into multiple files. For example split the files into 20 files and create twenty thread and assign each file to each thread. Each thread generate one report so 20 thread will generate 20 reports and finally marge all the report into one file. If you are inserting into a DB table no need to merge.